# MODISTools mt_subset() warning/error - A code that once worked now doesn't

Tags: r, r-modis

I've been working on a project about air pollutants and vegetation index. About the vegetation index (VI), I'm using the MODISTools package for R, and with the mt_subset() function I'm downlowading the VI data from a NASA website. The complete function is:

```
NDVI_data_Terra = 
    mt_subset(product = "MOD13Q1",
              site_id = "mx_distritofederal_mexico_city",
              band = "250m_16_days_NDVI",
              start = "2001-01-01",
              end = "2020-12-31",
              km_lr = 2,
              km_ab = 2,
              site_name = "CDMX",
              internal = TRUE,
              progress = FALSE)
```

A couple of months ago I ran the code without a problem, but now that I try to use the function the following warning pops up:

```
Warning messages:
1: 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 
2: 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 
3: 7b0a20202274797065223a202261626f75743a626c616e6b222c0a2020227469746c65223a2022496e7465726e616c20536572766572204572726f72222c0a20202264657461696c223a20225468652073657276657220656e636f756e746572656420616e20696e7465726e616c206572726f7220616e642077617320756e61626c6520746f20636f6d706c65746520796f757220726571756573742e204569746865722074686520736572766572206973206f7665726c6f61646564206f7220746865726520697320616e206572726f7220696e20746865206170706c69636174696f6e2e222c0a202022737461747573223a203530300a7d0a 
4: 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 
5: 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 
6: 7b0a20202274797065223a202261626f75743a626c616e6b222c0a2020227469746c65223a2022496e7465726e616c20536572766572204572726f72222c0a20202264657461696c223a20225468652073657276657220656e636f756e746572656420616e20696e7465726e616c206572726f7220616e642077617320756e61626c6520746f20636f6d706c65746520796f757220726571756573742e204569746865722074686520736572766572206973206f7665726c6f61646564206f7220746865726520697320616e206572726f7220696e20746865206170706c69636174696f6e2e222c0a202022737461747573223a203530300a7d0a 
7: 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 
8: 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 
9: 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
```

But sometimes, when I re-run the code I get the following error:

```
Error: 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
```

I have no idea what is happening. Anyone can help me with this?

PD: Apparently the package was updated, but I'm getting the following message, when I load it:

```
> library(MODISTools)
Warning message:
package ‘MODISTools’ was built under R version 4.0.5
```

I have the latest version of RStudio, so no idea what is happening.

Comment: Do you also have the latest version of R? try `R.version.string` in console to see your version

Comment: Okay, that was the problem. I updated R and now everything works fine (I thought R was updated alongside RStudio). Thanks!